# Android Actionbar Custom Background Glitch

Tags: android, android-actionbar, drawable

I have created a custom Drawable class called ActionbarBackground which implements some special drawing behavior for the background of my Actionbar.  When I test the app on a tablet I get the following glitch:

When the app launches the contents of the actionbar are drawn below the background, pushing the contents of the entire Activity down.

Example:
[image]

Upon touching the screen, a redraw is done and the contents of the actionbar disappear altogether.  The contents of the Activity then shifts up.

Example: 
[image]

This problem occurs across 2 activities and I don't know why.  I tried supplying a custom drawable from an XML resource and everything worked fine, but this background requires programmatic drawing.

The actionbar is setup like this:

```
this.getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
this.getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.actionbar_icon_and_title);
this.getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ActionbarBackground(this));
```

The implementation of the ActionbarBackground generally looks like this:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    // Do special drawing on canvas object
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    // Do nothing
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter filter) {
    // Do nothing
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?